# Premature end to script?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have been having issues with a premature end to script error and a traceback error.

The code below is modifyStudent.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import cgi, cgitb
import dbConnect
import menuHelper

cgitb.enable()

formData = cgi.FieldStorage()

firstName = menuHelper.getNameValue(formData, "firstName")
lastName = menuHelper.getNameValue(formData, "lastName")

# Tell the browser what kind of data to expect 
print ("Content-type: text/html\n")

print("<h2>Modify Student</h2>")

menuHelper.printMenuLink()

print("<br><br>")

isUpdate = dbConnect.getStudentData(lastName, firstName)
print("isUpdate=", isUpdate)

print('<center><form method="post" action="modifyStudentHandler.py">',   
        '<input type="hidden" name="isUpdate" value=' + str(isUpdate) + '>', 
        'First Name:', '<input type="text" name="firstName" value=' + firstName + ' readonly>', "<br>" 
        'Last Name: ', '<input type="text" name="lastName" value=' + lastName + ' readonly>', "<br>",
        # Fields for the grades.  
        'Hw 1: ', '<input type="numbers" name="hw1">', "<br>",
        'Hw 2: ', '<input type="numbers" name="hw2">', "<br>",
        'Hw 3: ', '<input type="numbers" name="hw3">', "<br>",
        'Midterm: ', '<input type="numbers" name="midterm">', "<br>",
        'Final: ', '<input type="numbers" name="final">', "<br>",
        # Submit button 
        '<input type="submit" value="Save">',
      '</form></center>',
     '</center>');

  dbConnect.closeConnection()
```

I am currently running a web app which I am trying to add this feature for a project, however I get the following errors:

```
[error] [client 24.169.14.133] Premature end of script headers: modifyStudent.py, referer: http://34.193.0.192/cgi-bin/menu.py
[error] [client 24.169.14.133] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://34.193.0.192/cgi-bin/menu.py
[error] [client 24.169.14.133]   File "/var/www/devApp/cgi-bin/modifyStudent.py", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://34.193.0.192/cgi-bin/menu.py
[error] [client 24.169.14.133]     import menuHelper.py, referer: http://34.193.0.192/cgi-bin/menu.py
```

Why am I getting these errors?

Comment: this is so 90s. Use a python framework like django

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is around how HTTP works. The standard is that the input is expected to be:

```
header lines
blank line
HTML Content
```

your line:

```
print ("Content-type: text/html\n")
```

is a header and then there is no blank line before the payload.

Hence you probably want:

```
print ("Content-type: text/html\n\n") # note the extra \n
print("<h2>Modify Student</h2>")
```

So your output becomes:

```
Content-type: text/html

<h2>Modify Student</h2>
.... other HTML.
```

As an aside your HTML is poorly formed as you should really have:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>your HTML goes here</body>
</html>
```

as a mimimum. If you had the payload as proper, well-formed HTML then the headline providing the content type would almost-certainly not be required.